# Change target background color of transition of buttons in bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, hover, css-transitions

I want to change how a button behaves when the mouse hovers over it. By default the background of the buttons gets darker when hovering over it. I wanted to change this behavior by modifying the variables in the `_variables.scss` file in the bootstrap source. But the only variable I could find concerning this matter was:

`$btn-transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out !default;`

but I could not figure out what variables this transition is referring to? Can I somehow change the target background-color of this transition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `btn-transition` var isn't defining the color of the `background-color`. It's defining the [CSS transition properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property). These are the properties that get animated during the transition.

You're looking for the `button-variant` @mixin. Look at the parameters for the mixin:

```
button-variant(
  $background,
  $border,
  $hover-background: darken($background, 7.5%), 
  $hover-border: darken($border, 10%), 
  $active-background: darken($background, 10%), 
  $active-border: darken($border, 12.5%)
) { .. }
```

As you can see `$background` and `$border` are required params. All the other params are optional. So you would redefine the button colors by changing those optional params. For example, here I make the `$hover-background` 30% darker (overriding the default of 7.5% darker)...

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors{
  .btn-#{$color} {
    @include button-variant($value, $value, darken($value,30%), darken($value,10%), darken($value,10%), darken($value,12.5%));
  }
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/ybbHC4JUZN

You can change the params as needed.

Comment: I know thats why I wrote "Can I somehow change the target background-color of this transition?"

Comment: As expained, `$hover-background` is the "target" (end of transition) background-color.

Comment: One last problem I am having with this is that I can't seem to replace `darken($value,30%)` with `opacify($value,.7) ` although I included `opacity .15s ease-in-out` into the `$btn-transition:` what am I missing?